# unable to update parent from child

Tags: react-native

The included code is almost running.  I'm trying to restart the count where it left off when I toggle the device.  I'm getting the following error message:

```
 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you 
 return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant 
 to call this function rather than return it.
```

here's what I was attempting:

1)pass as this.props.count class App this.state.count (this creates the starting point of the counter

2) pass a callback function from APP to COUNTER that will update APP.state.count (I do this inside of COUNTERS Inc method)

NOTE: it's a little tricky to get ignorewarnings working if you don't have the right dependencies installed. lines 3, 4 and 5 can be deleted

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import ignoreWarnings from 'react-native-ignore-warnings';
ignoreWarnings(['Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated',
                'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated'])

class Count extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
    if(nextProps.count % 2 === 0)return true
    else return true
  }


  render(){
    return(
      <Text style={styles.count}>{this.props.count}</Text>
    )
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){

    super(props)
    this.state={
      count: this.props.count,
  }
  console.log(this)
}

componentDidMount(){
   this.interval=setInterval(this.inc,1000)

}
componentWillUnmount(){
  clearInterval(this.interval)
}

inc=()=>{
  //console.log(thisate)

  this.setState(prevState =>({
    count: prevState.count + 1,
  }))

  this.props.resetCount(this.state.count)

}

  render() {

    return (
       <View>
         <Count count={this.state.count}/>
       </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      show:true,
      count:0,
    }
  }
  toggle=()=> this.setState(prevState => ({
      show: !prevState.show
  }))

  resetCounter(count){
    this.setState({count: Count})
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state)
    if(this.state.show){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button title='toggle' onPress={this.toggle}/>
          <Counter
                   count={this.state.count}
                   resetCount={(count)=>{this.resetCounter(count)}} />

        </View>
    )
    }else{
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Button style={styles.count} title='toggle' onPress={this.toggle}/>
          <Text style={styles.count}> &nbsp;</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  count:{
    fontSize:48
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem i see, and i think the warning come from here, is you resetCounter function. You pass "Count" (a component) to the state. I think you would like to pass the argument : count. You could do it simply like this so there is not mistake :

```
  resetCounter(count){
    this.setState({count})
  }
```

Second thing is your callback way. You should do it like this :

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(){
super()

this.resetCounter = this.resetCounter.bind(this);    

this.state={
  show:true,
  count:0,
 }
}

resetCounter(count){
    this.setState({count: Count})
}

render(){
...
return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title='toggle' onPress={this.toggle}/>
      <Counter
               count={this.state.count}
               resetCount={this.resetCounter} />

    </View>
 ...
  )
 }
}
```

It's a lot better for performance and for reading.

Hope it help !

Comment: thanks, as you can see below I did catch the Count versus count problem.  Our instructor seems to be pushing binding using arrow notation.  He thinks readability is improved taking it out of the constructor

Comment: Yes i saw it just after i wrote my answer. About the binding, you can tell him that every time you don't bind a function and pass it like you do a new function is created in memory each time you call it. It result to be a really bad thing for performance. Some article talk about it on the internet ;)

Answer (score 0):

just a typo! yureka.

```
resetCounter(count){
this.setState({count: Count})
}
```

needs to be:

```
resetCounter(count){
this.setState({count: count})
}
```